# Can't remove header from mathematically generated column in QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following formula in `D1` of my Google spreadsheet:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(B:B, "SELECT "&A1&"/Col1"))
```

It produces the header `quotient(5())` in `D1` that I don't know how to remove using the **LABEL** clause.

Any idea how I can remove that header?

[Link to example Google Sheets spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bo4x3D6-L3WKdL7VzA2grtBPNb5szEg09iGCF576QDs/edit)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 5 | 5 |  | `quotient(5())` | 1 | 2.5 | 1.666666667 | 1.25 | 1 |
| **2** |  | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **3** |  | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** |  | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** |  | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) [TOROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459) [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

---

## QUERY

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(B:B, "SELECT "&A1&"/B label "&A1&"/B ''"))
```

- you simply need to specify the column to label, `"&A1&"/B` in this case.
- FYI, I used `B` instead of `Col1` simply because it is fewer characters.

[image]

## ARRAYFORMULA

<sup>**Either of the following seems simpler**</sup>

```
=TOROW(ARRAYFORMULA(A1/B:B),2)
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1/TOROW(B:B,1))
```

[image]